# Using supertest in WebStorm produce 'Argument type is not assignable to parameter type' and 'Unresolved function or method'

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, webstorm, supertest

I have a nodejs project developed in WebStorm IDE. I'm using Mocha with supertest as my unit test framework.

WebStorm showed 2 warnings: `Argument type app|exports|module.exports is not assignable to parameter type Function|Server` and `Unresolved function or method get()`.

I've tried to download and install supertest libraries from `File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> JavaScript -> Libraries -> Download` but nothing happened. So I downloaded them directly from https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/supertest and added them manually but WebStorm still produced the same warnings.

This is my server.js code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).end();
});

app.listen(3000);

module.exports = app;
```

This is my servertest.js code:

```
/* eslint-env mocha*/

const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('../server');

describe('GET /', () => {
  it('should respond OK', (done) => {
    request(app) //Argument type app|exports|module.exports is not 
                 //assignable to parameter type Function|Server
        .get('/') //Unresolved function or method
        .expect(200, done);
  });
});
```

How do I get rid of these warnings?

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me (WebStorm 2016.2):

[image]

Enabled libraries: `Node.js Core`, `ECMAScript 6`, `HTML`, `HTML5/ECMAScript5`, `Jasmine Definitely Typed`. The latter is not actually necessaty, as WebStorm can resolve '`describe()`', etc. from Mocha node_modules, but allows to avoid inspections about missing imports for jasmine stuff.

Seems you have some definitions in your project that conflict with your `request` definition. What code are you taken to when you Ctrl+click on `request`?

Comment: When I Ctrl+clicked on `request`, it took me to node_modules/supertest/index.js.

Comment: For the sake of future googlers, adding `jasmine-DefinitelyTyped` fixes the inspection "Argument type function is not assignable to parameter type ActionFunction"